# Access SQL: How to use code to represent "Next Tuesday"?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010

Quick question.  I am attempting to select several records from various tables, WHERE a date field is less than or equal to (<=) two weeks from whenever the next Tuesday is.  I can't seem to figure out how to get it to look for the next chronological Tuesday though.

This is the current WHERE clause, which looks for today's date and then adds 14 (today happens to be Tuesday).

*WHERE qryLeadtimeSchedule.[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]<=NOW()+14*

How would I modify this to look for the next Tuesday on any given day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Switch`and`Weekday`functions. This code assumes your week starts on Weekday 2 (the second parameter to the Weekday function), which is Monday in the odd world of VBA.

Try this:

```
SELECT [Scheduled Date Dispositioned], 
Switch(
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=1,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+1+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=2,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+7+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=3,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+6+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=4,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+5+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=5,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+4+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=6,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+3+14,
    Weekday([Scheduled Date Dispositioned],2)=7,[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]+2+14
    ) as [14 days from next tuesday] 
FROM YourTable
```

What it does is to evaluate the current Weekday and then return this date + as many days that are needed to get to next Tuesday + 14. So for example if Weekday(Date()) is 1 for Monday, add 1 to get the next Tuesday and add 14 for your offset. If by *next Tuesday* you mean the Tuesday in the week following this you might have to adjust the value added (+7 for another week).

Comment: Hmmm, using a switch statement does seem like it would work.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: OK, so since this is part of the conditions in a WHERE statement, I'm not sure how to properly integrate this (Syntax-wise).  It currently looks like this:

WHERE (SELECT qryLeadtimeSchedule.[Scheduled Date Dispositioned],
Switch(statement here) AS [14 days from next tuesday] 
FROM qryLeadtimeSchedule), qryLeadtimeSchedule.[Scheduled Date Dispositioned]<=[14 days from next tuesday]
AND ...

The AND... represents my other conditions.

Comment: Try `where qryLeadtimeSchedule.[Scheduled Date Dispositioned] <= Switch(...)` where the switch-statement goes at the end.

Comment: I think may have just done it!  I had no idea that I could stick a SWITCH in a WHERE clause.  Thanks!